# How do I make collisions?

Tags: python-3.x, collision, python-curses

I am making a python curses program and I need to know how to make collisions. It is an open world game.

```
`import curses

stdscr = curses.initscr()
curses.initscr()
curses.noecho()
curses.cbreak() 
stdscr.keypad(True)
key = stdscr.getkey()
player = "@"
x, y = [55, 14]
x2, y2 = [53, 14]
while True:
   try:
        key = stdscr.getkey()
    except:
        key = None
    
    if key == "KEY_LEFT":
        x -= 1
    elif key == "KEY_RIGHT":
        x += 1
    elif key == "KEY_UP":
        y -= 1
    elif key == "KEY_DOWN":
        y += 1 
        if x == 55 and y == 14:
            y -= 1                
    stdscr.clear()
    stdscr.addstr(y2, x2, "###########")
    stdscr.addstr(y, x, player)
    stdscr.refresh()'
```

I only have a few months of coding experience so maybe it looks nooby.

I tried this:
`if x == 53 and y == 14:`
But it would be tedious.